# NTLDR missing Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, bootloader, ntldr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [missing NTLDR / no CD drive recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/89744/missing-ntldr-no-cd-drive-recognition)

I have a Windows XP system and the NTLDR error appears. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

See the following articles from Microsoft Support:

- [How to troubleshoot the "NTLDR Is Missing" error message in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318728/en-us)
- [Windows may not start and you may receive an "NTLDR is missing" error message if Windows is not up-to-date and there are too many files in the root folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320397/en-us)